# emtrends with broken stick model

Tags: r, breakpoints, emmeans

I'm fitting a broken stick model with and would like to use `emtrends()` to pull out the slope values before and after the breakpoint. The code here is a simplified toy version of data and analysis. I can't quite figure out how to get the slopes - seem to get identical values for before and after breakpoint. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(emmeans)

## toy data
df <- structure(list(Year = c(11, 11, 13, 13,  15,  15,  16,  16,  17, 
17, 18, 18, 14, 14), YearFac = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("11", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"), class = "factor"), Class = c("A", "B",    "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), Mean = c(3.5, 3.7,    3.7, 4.2, 3.7, 
4.5, 3.3, 4.9, 3.2, 5.8, 3.2, 6.3, NA, NA), YearPostTest = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0)), row.names = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L), class = "data.frame")

# breakpoint model
mod <- lm(Mean ~ Year + YearPostTest + Year:Class + 
                            YearPostTest:Class, data = df)

df$Pred <- predict(mod, newdata = df)
# plot data and predictions
ggplot(df) +
 geom_point(aes(x = Year, y = Mean, colour = Class)) +
 geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = Pred, colour = Class))

# make a new dataset with a few values - specifically, want to see slopes for A and for B 
# classes before and after breakpoint
new <- data.frame(YearPostTest = c(0, 1, 0, 1), 
   Year = c(13, 18, 13, 18), Class = c("A", "A", "B", "B")) 
emtrends(mod, ~Class|YearPostTest, var = "Year", data = new, 
   covnest = TRUE, cov.reduce = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method doesn't work because the slope depends on both `Year` and `YearPostTest`, and the latter is being held constant when computing the difference quotients.

The simplest way to do this is to write a function that creates a broken line:

```
> brok.line = function(x, knot)
+     cbind(x, (x > knot) * (x - knot))

> modmod = lm(Mean ~ brok.line(Year, 14) * Class, data = df)

> emtrends(modmod, ~ Class | Year, var = "Year", data = new, cov.reduce = FALSE)

Year = 13:
 Class Year.trend     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A         0.0875 0.0893  6   -0.131  0.30593
 B         0.0875 0.0893  6   -0.131  0.30593

Year = 18:
 Class Year.trend     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A        -0.1663 0.0662  6   -0.328 -0.00426
 B         0.5487 0.0662  6    0.387  0.71074

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

### Addendum

Another thing to know is that specifying `data` is *not* a substitute for an `at` specification. We could get exactly the same results as above via

```
> emtrends(modmod, ~ Class | Year, var = "Year", 
+          at = list(Year = c(13, 18)))
```

The only reason it worked in your example is because `cov.reduce = FALSE` yielded the same set of covariate values. However, note that for the original model `mod`:

```
> summary(ref_grid(mod, data = new, cov.reduce = FALSE, nesting = NULL))
 Year YearPostTest Class prediction     SE df
   13            0 A           3.68 0.1073  7
   18            0 A           4.06 0.3458  7
   13            1 A           3.44 0.0916  7
   18            1 A           3.82 0.2512  7
   13            0 B           3.96 0.1073  7
   18            0 B           4.45 0.3458  7
   13            1 B           4.41 0.0916  7
   18            1 B           4.90 0.2512  7
```

The `new` dataset generated 8 cases, even though `new` has only 4 rows. That is because the reference grid consists of all possible combinations of the predictor levels -- not just the ones that appear in `data`.

#### One more thing

I noticed that `mod` and `modmod` are not exactly the same, because `mod` excludes the main effect of `Class`. In this particular example, that effect is very small; but in general, you should include `Class` in the model because otherwise you are assuming both classes have the same intercept:

```
> year0 = data.frame(Year = c(0,0), YearPostTest = c(0,0), Class = c("A","B"))

> predict(mod, newdata = year0)
      1       2 
2.68125 2.68125 

> predict(modmod, newdata = year0)
      1       2 
2.54375 2.81875
```

[image]

Comment: PS - I was concerned that we get exactly the same slope for the two classes at year 13. However, this is a consequence of the data. I confirmed that if I change the 4th `Mean` to 3.9, the result is four different slopes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and for bonus points - catching the missing CI main effect... Works like a charm!